# Go to recovery mode on device without volume key

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, tablet

Is there a universal way to enter recovery mode on an Android device **with only one turn on/off button**? 
I have a tablet (Navon Raptor 7) like this and I can't figure it out. An other problem is that although it can boot and get to the launcher, basically I can't start any application or get to the settings (it says 'xy application stopped' etc.) so **I can't even activate debug mode** and use adb to achieve this. That's why I want to do a hard reset from recovery...

Comment: Welcome to  Android Enthusiasts! The question-and-answer format of this site works best if you put each question in a separate question post. Please [edit] your post down to one question, and create new posts to ask any further questions. You'll get better answers that way. To the first question: No, key-combos differ between devices (see also our [recovery-mode tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/recovery-mode/info)).

Comment: My only question is what's in the title. The other stuff is just for prevent answers like 'go to the settings...'. So maybe I should disassemble and see if there is an inner switch or something?

Comment: You might try a Google-Search on ["Navon Raptor 7" hard-reset](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Navon+Raptor+7%22+hard-reset&ie=UTF-8&nfpr=1). There are even some youtube tuts listed. Most of the results are Hungarian, though. I was hoping for a link to hard-reset.com (they always list along how to enter recovery mode for that), but unfortunately there seems to be none...

Comment: I speak Hungarian but there seems to be absolutely nothing about reseting it with hard keys. I found out that this device is in close relationship with the Icoo D70 Pro II, which has slightly bigger community but still no hits for reseting.

Comment: According to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nFfJMU4dSz8) video, the "Navon raptor 7"" tablet is supposed to have the hardware volume buttons.  Are you saying that yours doesn't have them?

Comment: Yes, there are different variants and mine doesn't have them.

Comment: Does the device have any soft-keys? That is, "physical" buttons that are touch-only, instead of a depressable, moving button? If it does have soft-buttons, it may be able to register those from a cold boot and use a combo of one of those plus the power button to get into recovery mode.

Comment: Or possibly, it may have a feature similar to the Nook Simple Touch. If the NST detects it has been reboot 6 or more times without successfully booting to the desktop, it automatically initiates a full hardware reset, which returns it to the factory ROM image (and clears all data).

Comment: All of it's buttons are virtual, part of the screen and only appears when booted. It does fully boot up btw, it's just useless since I can't start any app and I have to constatntly press OK on the middle of the screen because processes contantly stop in the background. Maybe it's a virus, I have no idea.

Comment: try pushing on/off key many times during reboot

Answer (score 1):

You can use apps like Quick Boot or Rebooter or some root apps have this feature to go to recovery mode.. Use them

Comment: Yes, I found them in Google but every one of them starts like 'enable debug mode on the phone...' or not?

Comment: They just need root access

Comment: Thats bad enough because I have the original not rooted ROM on this tablet :C . Oh and I cant run any apps on the tablet, it's a total mess.

Comment: Without root access I think only way is hard key combos.

Comment: Yeah that is my conclusion too but how to do that with only 1 key?

Comment: Using only one key will do only the specified action. No use with that AFAIK

Comment: @CompanyCodeMonkey In almost every case, you can root the original ROM (commonly called **'stock ROM'**). The stock ROM comes unrooted when you buy the phone. But you can root it (without flashing any custom ROM such as Cyanogenmod), and rooted stock allows a lot more customization (through Xposed for example). You can also flash a custom ROM without rooting your stock ROM (it doesn't matter as long as you don't need to root for some other step in the process). Custom ROMs are usually already rooted since they are geared towards power users, and their features usually require root access.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command from an adb prompt to enter into your devices recovery mode without using a physical button during restart.

1) Start adb prompt on your PC / MAC / Linux

2) Make sure adb is running `adb start-server`

2) Make sure the device is present when you run: `adb devices`

3) Now run `adb reboot bootloader` and your device will restart into recovery mode

Comment: actually that will restart into fastboot mode